# Reactjs Nested Array Mapping

Tags: reactjs, nested-loops

Hi I am trying to map a nested array my json is like this

**JSON**

```
[
  {
    "cat_id": 24,
    "cat_name": "Test1",
    "parent_id": 0,
    "sub_cat": [
      {
        "cat_id": 30,
        "cat_name": "SubTest1",
        "parent_id": 24
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "cat_id": 18,
    "cat_name": "Test2",
    "parent_id": 0,
    "sub_cat": [
      {
        "cat_id": 32,
        "cat_name": "SubTest2",
        "parent_id": 18
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I tried this but got error  - Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","

```js
{

 categories.map((row, key)=>(
 
   <Nav.Link href="#" key={key}>{row.cat_name}</Nav.Link>
        
     {
       row.sub_cat.map((subcat, sub_key) => ( 
         <Nav.Link href="#">{subcat.cat_name}</Nav.Link>
         ))
     }
 
   ) )
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In react we can only have one parent JSX element, you need to wrap the contents of the second map with a parent element like React fragment:

```
{categories.map((row, key) => (
    <>
        <Nav.Link href="#" key={key}>
            {row.cat_name}
        </Nav.Link>
        {row.sub_cat.map((subcat, sub_key) => (
            <Nav.Link href="#">{subcat.cat_name}</Nav.Link>
        ))}
    </>
))}
```

Related docs:

- https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html
- https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/writing-markup-with-jsx#1-return-a-single-root-element

Also your data seems to have natural unique ids, so you had better to use them as key instead of the index.

```
{categories.map(row => (
    <>
        <Nav.Link href="#" key={row.cat_id}>
            {row.cat_name}
        </Nav.Link>
        {row.sub_cat.map(subcat => (
            <Nav.Link href="#" key={subcat.cat_id}>{subcat.cat_name}</Nav.Link>
        ))}
    </>
))}
```

Comment: Perfect thanks but where do I get to know more about on this topic??

Comment: @sanu in the official docs `https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html`

Comment: and `https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/writing-markup-with-jsx#1-return-a-single-root-element`